# What's the idiomatic way to convert a Result to a custom Fail impl?

Tags: rust

Currently, I'm turning a `Result` into an instance of my error enum that impls `Fail` like this:

```
fn bbswitch_write(data: &str) -> Result<(), BbswitchError> {
    match fs::write("/proc/acpi/bbswitch", data) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(e) => Err(BbswitchError::BbswitchNotAvailable { cause: e }.into()),
    }
}
```

but this feels very verbose, and I'd rather not write a four-line `match` statement every time I do something like this:

```
let contents = fs::read_to_string("/proc/acpi/bbswitch").expect("bbswitch not available");
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong that's making error handling unreasonably difficult, or a way I could structure something better to make it more convenient?

The rest of my code looks something like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate failure;

use std::fs;
use std::process::exit;
use failure::Error;

#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
enum BbswitchError {
    #[fail(display = "bbswitch not available")]
    BbswitchNotAvailable {
        #[fail(cause)]
        cause: std::io::Error,
    },
}

fn bbswitch_write(data: &str) -> Result<(), Error> {
    match fs::write("/proc/acpi/bbswitch", data) {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(e) => Err(BbswitchError::BbswitchNotAvailable { cause: e }.into()),
    }
}

fn power_on() -> Result<(), Error> {
    bbswitch_write("ON")?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    match power_on() {
        Ok(_) => {},
        Err(_) => exit(1),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That very simple just use [`map_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err):

```
fs::write("/proc/acpi/bbswitch", data)
    .map_err(|e| BbswitchError::BbswitchNotAvailable { cause: e }.into())
```